# How to make Server side validation on ajax call for values sent at controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Server side validation for values sent through ajax call.
Although i have applied some client side jquery validation 
but if somebody blocks client side javascript then it will fail.
I want to know how can i apply server side validation for ajax post values sent to a controller and can notify to client side.

My case is on ajax post i am sending some values taking from  a order site.
Like quanity, price, itemsize i want to know how can i validate these values at the controller.

```
var CustomCategory = {
    OnCustomClick: function (productID, productOptionID, itmPrice, qty) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Customization/GetProductCustomization?pId=' + productID + '&pOptionID=' + productOptionID + '&itmPrice=' + itmPrice + '&qty=' + qty,
            //url: 'Customization/vwGetProductCustomization',
            type: 'POST',
        }).success(function (data) {
            //alert(data);
            $("#myModal").html(data);
        });
    }
}
```

Like somebody makes quantity numeric functionality off for java script and send some wrong values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by implementing serverside model validation, and then expand to jquery unobtrusive validation.
There are a bunch of support for this by default, and you're only going to do some actual hard work if you need to create your own custom validation. To create a custom validator you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904976/client-side-validation-mvc-dropdown/19907185#19907185) and also read the provided link to get some more information.

To create som standard model validation you can just add them in your *ViewModel*

```
public class Movie {
public int ID { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Title { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Genre { get; set; }

[Range(1, 100)]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal Price { get; set; }

[StringLength(5)]
public string Rating { get; set; }
}
```

You need to import **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations** namespace to be able to use this *Attributes*. After that is done, just include **jquery.unobtrusive** script and before posting your form with ajax, just check if the form is valid, otherwise you can just return false:

```
if ($(form).valid()) {
    $.ajax({ .....
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

To make sure that nothing slips through, you also need to check your model in your controller

```
public ContentResult CheckForm(SomeViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    ...... //Do something
    }
    return vm;
}
```

The *IsValid* property will only return *true* if all validation attributes on your ViewModel are valid.